# setting the size of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a class that extends a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) called Row. I have a bunch of Row added to a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), the code is the following:

```
JFrame f=new JFrame();

JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel();
//southReviewPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,130));
rowPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rowPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
rowPanel.add(test1);
rowPanel.add(test1);
rowPanel.add(test2);
rowPanel.add(test3);
rowPanel.add(test4);
rowPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
rowPanel.setMaximumSize(rowPanel.getPreferredSize()); 
rowPanel.setMinimumSize(rowPanel.getPreferredSize());

f.setSize(new Dimension(300,600));

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(rowPanel);
sp.setSize(new Dimension(300,600));
f.add(sp);

f.setVisible(true);
```

where test1...etc is a Row. However when I resize the window the layout of the Row somehow becomes messy (it resizes as well)... how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Each layout manager has its own rules about what happens when the container is resized. Experiment and play.

In the case of a BoxLayout it should respect the maximum size of the components added to the panel so you can do:

```
childPanel.setMaximumSize( childPanel.getPreferredSize() );
```

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I did change using getPreferredSize and setMaximumSize as you suggested above (see my edited code)... still, it is as the code even doesn't exist. What about if I have a border layout? How do I set the size? It doesn't mention about BorderLayout on the link you gave above

Comment: Your edited code is NOT a SSCCE. Yes the link does mention a BorderLayout. There is no way you could have read the entire section in 6 minutes!!! A layout manager works on the components added to the panel, not the panel itself.

Comment: doesn't say anything there that would make it not resizable

Answer (score 1):

I took the code in http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java and adapted it with what you are trying to do, only using buttons instead of custom JPanels:

```
public class BoxLayoutDemo {
    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel();
        pane.add(rowPanel);

        rowPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rowPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        rowPanel.add(addAButton("Button 1"));
        rowPanel.add(addAButton("Button 2"));
        rowPanel.add(addAButton("Button 3"));
        rowPanel.add(addAButton("Button 4"));
        rowPanel.add(addAButton("5"));
        rowPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        rowPanel.setMaximumSize(rowPanel.getPreferredSize()); 
        rowPanel.setMinimumSize(rowPanel.getPreferredSize());
    }

    private static JButton addAButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        return button;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoxLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The end result is this:
[image]

As you can see, the button row is perfectly aligned. If you resize the JFrame, they stay aligned. Is that what you are looking for?